# Jmeter - How send data from response to URL?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I need to send "id" from response to the next request in URL (like - - send/request/"id").
 How do it right?

1. Response https://joxi.ru/1A5374vhDENjXm
2. Regular Expression Extractor https://joxi.ru/KAxv8ONUZL7lgm
3. Send "id" in URL https://joxi.ru/52aaP4EIExO702

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the variable you've created on the JSON Extractor:

```
${study_id}
```

[image]

Below you are using simply `Id`

[image]

More info on JMeter variables [here](http://thatsabug.com/2019/06/21/jmeter_2.html).

You regex is also wrong, try `"id":(\d+)`. This will capture on the first group any integer that follows the the *id* string.

But I would suggest to replace the Regular Expression Extractor for a [JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor/).

With this, you just need to indicate the JSON key that you are looking for.

[image]

In your case, `$.id`.

Comment: it does not help, https://joxi.ru/D2PxPWGtqX77j2,

Comment: My bad, it should be ${study_id}. I've updated the answer and linked a blog post where I give more details. Can you try this out?

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work https://joxi.ru/vAWJP0vCgEY6j2

Comment: There were some problems on the extraction as well. Could you check my new edit?

Comment: It's working, very grateful for the help!!!

Answer (score 0):

I hope you know the [Parameterization](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-parameterization-the-complete-guide/) and [Correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter/) concept in JMeter, so in this if we want to pass one value throughout the script then pass the variable name within dollar($) and curly braces'{..}' like this

```
${variable_name}
```

In your case here https://joxi.net/KAxv8ONUZL7lgm,
the variable name is written in the field 'Name of created variable' i.e 'study_id'

Also, If you want to check whether the variable's value is null or not then use **[Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler)** either at the end of script or place it where the variable is used in the request.